# How do I match a tag containing only the stated class, not any others, using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to use BeautifulSoup to match a tag with *only* the indicated `class` attribute, not the indicated `class` attribute and others? For example, in this simple HTML:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Title here
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="one two">
   some content here
  </div>
  <div class="two">
   more content here
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

is it possible to match only the `div` with `class="two"`, but not match the `div` with `class="one two"`? Unless I'm missing something, [that section](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Searching%20by%20CSS%20class) of the documentation doesn't give me any ideas. This is the code I'm using currently:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Title here
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="one two">
   should not be matched
  </div>
  <div class="two">
   this should be matched
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
div_two = soup.find("div", "two")
print(div_two.contents[0].strip())
```

I'm trying to get this to print `this should be matched` instead of `should not be matched`.

EDIT: In this simple example, I know that the only options for classes are `"one two"` or `"two"`, but in production code, I'll only know that what I want to match will have class `"two"`; other tags could have a large number of other classes in addition to `"two"`, which may not be known.

On a related note, it's also helpful to read the [documentation for version **4**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes), not version 3 as I previously linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
divs = soup.findAll('div', class="two")

for div in divs:
    if div['class'] == ['two']:
        pass # handle class="two"
    else:
        pass # handle other cases, including but not limited to "one two"
```

Comment: The only problem with this is the case where I don't know what other classes the tag will have. +1, but if possible, see my edit as well.

Comment: Since your answer is basically the same as mine, I'll accept it and remove my own answer if you incorporate the changes introduced in my edit.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano I appreciate the courtesy. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, below code helps you. Though I didn't try this one.

```
soup.find("div", { "class" : "two" })
```

Comment: Per the documentation, that's identical to `soup.find("div", "two")
`.